# Find the directional derivative

Tags: calculus

find the direction derivative of $f(x,y)=2\sqrt{x}-y^2$ at point $(1,3)$ in the direction toward the point $(3,1)$?

The answer is $\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}$ but i am getting $-\frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$

i did $$\vec u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \langle3,1\rangle$$
$$f_x= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$f_y=-2y$$
$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{10}}$$
$$=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}$$

Comment: Unit vector...of *what direction*?? The direction must be $\;(3,1)-(1,3)=(2,-2)\;$ , from point $\;(1,3)\;$ **towards** $\;(3,1)\;$

Answer (score 1):

The function is differentaible at the given point, so:

$$\nabla f=\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\,,\,\,-2y\right)\implies \nabla f(1,3)=\left(1,\,-6\right)$$

The direction is

$$(3,1)-(1,3)=(2,-2)\implies\;\text{normalized:}\;\;\frac1{2\sqrt2}(2,-2)$$

so the directional derivative wanted is

$$\nabla f(1,3)\cdot\frac1{2\sqrt2}(2,-2)=\frac1{2\sqrt2}(2,-2)(1,-6)=\frac7{\sqrt2}$$